# Allocating space for array of structs, Valgrid invalid read

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, valgrind, realloc

I have a dynamically allocated array of structs. I'm writing a function which adds new struct entries to that array. Each time the function is called -- space for the array should be reallocated.

```
pa->arr = realloc(pa->arr, (pa->count + 1) * sizeof(struct product));
if (pa->arr == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

The array of structs **arr** is maintained by another structure **struct product_array *pa** which apart from the pointer to the array ***arr** contains **count** (number of array entries).

```
struct product_array {
    struct product *arr;
    unsigned int count;
};

struct product {
    char *title;  
};
```

Also, I have to allocate space separately for title field.

```
char *temp = malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
    if (temp == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(temp, title);
        title = temp;

    pa->arr[pa->count].title = title;
```

The function works, but I get Valgrid complains about "Invalid read of size 8". I would really appreciate if you could help me with that.

Comment: Compile with -g to include debug info. Then valgrind will tell you exactly where the invalid read is occurring. Problems like this are very difficult to diagnose only seeing snippets on a web post. You need to be able to debug the program live.

Comment: Assigning `pa->arr = realloc(pa->arr, ...)` directly is the classic `realloc` mistake: you should assign to `temp`, NULL-check, and them assign to `pa->arr`. Otherwise, you leak the old value of `pa->arr` on `realloc` failure.

Answer (score 0):

The error you got suggests that you are reading from an un-allocated memory.

maybe you are missing this:
`pa->arr[pa->count - 1].title = title;` not `pa->arr[pa->count].title = title;`

** i wanted to post this as a comment but still don't have enough reputation!